# How to run a nats ws server on localhost

Tags: ssl, websocket, tls1.2, nats.io

I have a nats server on localhost or local docker with WS configuration. Nats require tls for websocket. I created a cert and key. But, on connect it throws an error `TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:61732: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority`. What should I do?

Comment: Probably you certificate is not trusted, so your machine refuses connection.

Answer (score 1):

For test env, you need to create a conf file like this:

```sh
# ws.conf
websocket {
    # Specify a host and port to listen for websocket connections
    #
    # listen: "host:port"

    # It can also be configured with individual parameters,
    # namely host and port.
    #
    # host: "hostname"
    port: 443

    # For test environments, you can disable the need for TLS
    # by explicitly setting this option to `true`
    #
    no_tls: true
}
```

I called this as ws.conf here, but you could name it as you wish. Note I explicitly set the `no_tls` to true and didn't passed any certificate.

## Docker way

After that you need to create a Dockerfile, since the entrypoint of nats image is the nats executable, we could do this:

```
FROM nats:alpine

COPY ws.conf ws.conf

CMD [ "-c", "ws.conf" ]
```

Note in CMD I'm passing some params, let me explain:

- `-c` is a shortcurt for `--config` option for nats server
- `ws.conf` is the config file we created

Now you could build and run this image. Or alternatively you could create a docker-compose to do it for you, something like that:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nats-ws:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
        - 443:443
        - 4222:4222
```

## Standalone way

After create the ws.conf start the nats with the params equal to docker way.

```sh
nats-server -c path/to/ws.conf
```

Thats it, if everthing is right you will see this message in nats logs / stdout:

```sh
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854288 [INF] Starting nats-server
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854402 [INF] Version: 2.2.2
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854407 [INF] Git: [a5f3aab]
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854411 [INF] Name: NCXFZRJ6L2PYQM6DND5YRKZA5OMQBQTFGH7ATZULU3US7KBWQDU4RKE3
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854416 [INF] ID: NCXFZRJ6L2PYQM6DND5YRKZA5OMQBQTFGH7ATZULU3US7KBWQDU4RKE3
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.854421 [INF] Using configuration file: ws.conf
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.858602 [INF] Listening for websocket clients on ws://0.0.0.0:443
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.858643 [WRN] Websocket not configured with TLS. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.859209 [INF] Listening for client connections on 0.0.0.0:4222
[1] 2021/04/25 18:29:52.859696 [INF] Server is ready
```

### Refs

- [nats flags](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/flags)
- [websocker config file](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/websocket/websocket_conf)

Comment: Is the only way to pass in the .conf file? I want to change the websocket port via the command line flags - I'm running docker compose and I read in environment variables from another file - I want to keep them in that file instead of separating them into ws.conf...

Comment: Well for anyone interested, I just realized the NATS .conf file can read environment variables (prefix with $). So just add it in your docker-compose.yaml and use it in your .conf file.

https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration#variables

Comment: Interesting and also a good use case. I will update the answer.